# Is there an overhead difference between include_once() and conditional include?

Tags: php, include

Is there any difference in overhead for using include_once vs. conditional include?

this:

include_once('logins.php');

vs this:

if( !in_array( 'logins.php',get_included_files() ) ) {
  include('logins.php');
}

Obviously include_once is a lot easier to type and possibly/probably performs the same operation behind the scenes as the conditional include performs. But I don't know for sure and I seem to remember reading that lots of "include_once"s add a lot of overhead to the code.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to include a file once, use `include_once`. Keeping your own registry is just more code to write, document, debug and unnecessary noise when `include_once` *works*.

The only time I would recommend doing otherwise is if your application had performance issues, and measuring the issue showed the bottle neck was including files with `include_once`. I can almost guarantee that won't be the case.

Comment: For some reason it feels lazy to use include_once, as if I can't control the code well enough to make sure I don't include things a bunch of times. But I think you're right, and I will use it at least during testing. After that, I think I'll try to organize the code to work with include().